# Extracting values from the

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```html
    <a href="javascript:popUp('http://www.abcd.com/calendar/event.php?calendar=1&amp;category=&amp;event=43221&amp;date=2016-02-22','520','520');" onmouseout="javascript:hideEventDetailsBox();" onmouseover="javascript:eventDetailsBox('&lt;b&gt;Time:&lt;/b&gt; 9:00\xa0AM-4:30\xa0PM&lt;br /&gt;&lt;b&gt;Title:&lt;/b&gt; Hello!&lt;br /&gt;&lt;b&gt;Location:&lt;/b&gt; Cultural World N Avenue &lt;br /&gt;&lt;b&gt;Description:&lt;/b&gt; abcdefghi');" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:small;color:#000000;">
```

I want to scrap the  fields(Time/Title/Description/Location from the above HTML using Beautiful Soup4. I am unable to access these attributes inside "onmouseover". I tried the below :

```html
print g_dataItem.contents[5].find_all(onmouseover=True)
for tag in g_dataItem.contents[5].findAll(onmouseover=True):
    print  tag['onmouseover']
```

to get the part.

javascript:eventDetailsBox('**Time:** 9:00 AM-4:30 PM
**Title:** Hello!
**Location:** Cultural World N Avenue
**Description:** abcdefghi');

But once I get the above, which is in unicode, I am unable to extract the fields from here. Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<a href="javascript:popUp('http://www.abcd.com/calendar/event.php?calendar=1&amp;category=&amp;event=43221&amp;date=2016-02-22','520','520');" onmouseout="javascript:hideEventDetailsBox();" onmouseover="javascript:eventDetailsBox('&lt;b&gt;Time:&lt;/b&gt; 9:00\xa0AM-4:30\xa0PM&lt;br /&gt;&lt;b&gt;Title:&lt;/b&gt; Hello!&lt;br /&gt;&lt;b&gt;Location:&lt;/b&gt; Cultural World N Avenue &lt;br /&gt;&lt;b&gt;Description:&lt;/b&gt; abcdefghi');" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:small;color:#000000;">"""

b = BeautifulSoup(data)
onmouseover = b.find_all('a')[0].get('onmouseover').split("'")[1]

b = BeautifulSoup(onmouseover)
results = [{b_tag.text:b_tag.next_sibling.strip()} for b_tag in b.find_all('b')]
print results
```

**Results:**

```
[
    {u'Time:': u'9:00\xa0AM-4:30\xa0PM'},
    {u'Title:': u'Hello!'},
    {u'Location:': u'Cultural World N Avenue'},
    {u'Description:': u'abcdefghi'}
]
```